# Solr 4.3.1 Data-Import command

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm currently using Solr 4.3.1. i have configured dih for my solr. i would like to do a full import through command prompt. I know the url will be something like this http://localhost:8983/solr/corename/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true  is there any method i can do this without using curl ?

Thanks

Edit

```
string Text = "http://localhost:8983/solr/Latest_TextBox/dataimport?command=full-import&clean=true&commit=true";
var wc = new WebClient();
var Import = wc.DownloadString(Text);
```

Currently using the above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call it like a normal REST url that's it !! I am using it in my application for importing and indexing data from my Local drive and it just works fine ! :) . Use HttpURLConnection to make a request and capture response to see whether it was successful or not . You don't need any specific API to do that . This is a sample code to make a GET request correctly in C# .Try data import handler url with this, it may work !

```
Console.WriteLine("Making API Call...");
                using (var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate }))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/");
                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("answers?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow").Result;
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Result: " + result);
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What have you posted ??? I can only see one of code . please edit your code in your original question.

Comment: You don't have to edit my answer and paste your code there . I asked you to modify your own question and put code there .

Comment: Sorry ...I'm new to Stackoverflow. My mistake

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to call the URL in some way - Solr only operates through a REST API. There is no command line API (the [command line tools](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/5eabffc79754f533654bcbc73ab6441e6059d45f/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/util/SolrCLI.java#L1570) available just talk to the API). So use your preferred way to talk to a HTTP endpoint, that being `curl`, `wget`, `GET` or what's available for your programming language of choice.

The bundled solrCli application does not have any existing command for triggering a full-import as far as I were able to see (which would just talk to the REST API by calling the URL you've already referenced).